# How can I control a Lego Technic infrared receiver with my phone (android)?

Tags: raspberry-pi, hardware, infrared, lego-mindstorms

I have set of Lego Technic motors + battery + IR remote and receiver. I'd like to use the receiver to control another motor (not lego) via a L298N motor controller board hooked up to my raspberry pi 3. Also I'd like to control it with my smartphone. Is this possible? And if yes how? I just need a solution for speaking to the IR receiver and getting my motor to respond. The motor is already running using a script I run via SSH.

Comment: These are a lot of questions at once. The answer will depend on your level of knowledge and/or whether you find matching libraries for whatever toolbox/programming language you want to use.

Comment: I really don't know a lot...also I use python

Comment: Then I suggest you go step by step. First, try to find a library that can drive these lego technic pieces. There are some (of different quality) out there, but I can't recommend one, as I haven't tried that.